# Install Pi-Hole without user interaction?

Tags: software-installation, vagrant, pi-hole

I would like to install Pi-Hole automatically inside Vagrant (VirtualBox). 
Therefore, in an automated script, it has to run to box start. 
Unfortunately, normally,
you have to answer multiple installation questions to install Pi-Hole,
e.g., IPv4 or 6, ...,
and you need keyboard interaction with the setup (by the user).

Is there any way or solution to install it without any interaction? 
How can I write it in a Bash script or Vagrantfile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [discussion](https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/pi-hole-as-part-of-a-post-installatie-script/3523/5) says you can create the configuration options in the file `/etc/pihole/setupVars.conf` (documented [here](https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/what-is-setupvars-conf-and-how-do-i-use-it/3533)) and run with the `--unattended` flag, eg:

```
curl -L https://install.pi-hole.net | bash /dev/stdin --unattended
```

Comment: Do you know by any chance what kind of hash is supposed to be used in WEBPASSWORD var?

Comment: Judging from the example and this [source file](https://github.com/pi-hole/AdminLTE/blob/master/scripts/pi-hole/php/password.php#L41), it is created with `hash('sha256',hash('sha256',$_POST["pw"]))`.

Comment: so for example the output of `echo -n P@ssw0rd | sha256sum`, which is `b03ddf3ca2e714a6548e7495e2a03f5e824eaac9837cd7f159c67b90fb4b7342` should set the pihole web interface password to `P@ssw0rd`... Wondering, why it might not work...

Comment: I guess because it's a double hash... Should be `echo -n P@ssw0rd | sha256sum | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | sha256sum`

Comment: Nope... Still doesn't work (((

Comment: Says wrong password

Comment: You might have to replace your `cut` with something like `awk '{printf "%s",$1 }'` to exclulde the newline at the end for the second hash.

Comment: Returns error `255 Failed to open terminal` everytime!

Comment: Install and set your password up then copy the password value from /etc/pihole/setupVars.conf then you can tear down and install with your Terraform/Ansible scripts.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value for the passord, according to the [source:](https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole/blob/1b809e4e8ea442cd2a3cc54206429fabd58cce05/advanced/Scripts/webpage.sh#L95)

You can do the following: (I don't recommend leaving your password in your bash history)

```
export PASSWORD="p@ssword"
return=$(echo -n "$PASSWORD" | sha256sum | sed 's/\s.*$//')
return=$(echo -n "$return" | sha256sum | sed 's/\s.*$//')
```